# Set minter wallet address as creator of NFT in opensea

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, opensea

We've deployed a smart contract on ethereum blockchain. You can check it out on [etherscan website](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb28360ce2debebd8689a13e3539853026e9122f9). This contract is called *xarb*. Now the problem is all tokens minted by this contract has *xarb* as the creator of token in [opensea](https://opensea.io). I know a solution could be having a contract factory, But I also know that [foundation marketplace](https://foundation.app) has one and only one smart contract for minting and has no trouble with token creator address. Anybody knows what method is used by opensea to find the creator of token out?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by contacting opensea support. It seems they distinguish contracts of marketplaces and collectibles by your introduction. So I created a ticket at [opensea support website](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/requests/new) and told them we are a marketplace. Not a collectible or collection. They are really slow though. It took about 15 days for us to change our smart contract tokens' creators.